# Can anyone explain what do 3rd and 5th line exactly do

Tags: javascript

I've just started to practice and I cant find any info. Why is "o" defined as blank and later reappearing in other line of code as different.Thank you in advance.

```js
function TriangleOfStars() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    var o = "";
    for (var j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
      o += "*"
    }
    console.log(o);
  }
}
TriangleOfStars();
```

Comment: Check the browsers console to see what happens. ;)

Comment: var o=""; initial variable = empty string, o += "*"; append "*" to o

Comment: It needs to empty the string so it can start fresh on each line.

Comment: `o += "*"` is just a shorthand way of saying `o = o + "*"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third line is defining the variable o as an empty string (as you mentioned). The fifth line is adding an asterisk. That is what the += sign means. So every time it reaches line 5, an asterisk will be appended to the string.

As said in the comment by Tyr, it is useful to look at the console because that way you can see the result is a triangle pointing upwards. That will help you to understand it.

Comment: If this was helpful and considered correct, please mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

For every iteration in the outer for loop, `o` is defined as empty. The inner loop will concatinate a `*` to `o` to build up a line of `*` based on the outer for loop like this:

```
*           // i = 1
**          // i = 2
***         // i = 3 
****        // i = 4
*****       // i = 5
******      // i = 6
*******     // i = 7
********    // i = 8
*********   // i = 9
**********  // i = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Here goes some information:

[Variable initalization:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

```
var o="";
```

[Assignment operators:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

```
o += "*"
```